# Get name of current foreground application via shell scripting and via C++

Tags: c++, linux, shell

I need to write an application which runs in the background and tracks the application in the foreground being used by the user. This information will be fetched once every minute.

I need the command to be used for find the foreground application at any given instance of time via:

1. Shell scripting
2. C++ (in linux environment)

Thanks...

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I suppose the question is clear enough, and has also been answered.. Why the -1!

Answer (score 3):

To get the `windowID` of the active window:

```
xdotool getactivewindow
```

To get information about window with `windowID`:

```
xwininfo -id windowID
```

Perhaps used like this:

```
echo $(xwininfo -id $(xdotool getactivewindow) | head -n2 | sed 's/^[^"]*"\([^"]*\)"/\1/')
```

Should return the name of the currently selected application.

Somewhat ugly regex for sed, xwininfo shows the name of the window in quotes on the second line of output.  Adjust as needed.  xwininfo also gives much more info, have a look.

Comment: If you were to think about running this in a cron job, you run into issues involving the `DISPLAY` env-variable __AND__ .xauth cookies.  This would easiest be done by running some script from that user's desktop.